# How to connect skype with Facebook

Tags: skype, facebook

Do you know how to connect skype with facebook for ubuntu user like me? 
and how to do it ?

like at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DO5GbYHv7HM&feature=player_embedded)

Comment: That video talks about Skype *for Windows*. You're on Ubuntu.

Comment: It still doesn't work on Linux, am I right? Just downloaded the latest Skype version on the latest Ubuntu and can't see any opportunity to connect with my facebook account like I can do in the windows version ... :)

Answer (score 8):

Connecting Skype with Facebook is not (yet) supported in the latest version of Skype for Linux. The video you posted shows using Skype on Microsoft Windows.

[Proof : 12/1/2013](http://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/connect-skype-to-facebook-with-linux/td-p/1202238)

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's pretty much different approach. I believe that there are internet messengers that support facebook, skype (with some additional plugins) and some other chat services, I'll present one of them:

Pidgin.
   apart from supporting bunch of services, by adding several plugins, we can get skype and facebook chat services working too.

- Skype. This page explains how to add the plugin http://eion.robbmob.com/
- Facebook. Actually, the same developer made this pidgin-facebook plugin -  http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/

This approach is morelike of integrating everything in one. If you don't prioritize this all-in-one technique, you can use skype IM and empathy IM, which supports facebook chat itself.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. It is not about using the Facebook Chat and Skype in one application, but about logging into Skype using a Facebook account instead of a Skype account, which is currently not possible in Skype for Linux.

Comment: The answer fits the question