# Error while trying to run Skype via Wine in Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit

Tags: wine, skype, playonlinux, winetricks

As many previous Windows users do, I hate what Microsoft has done with the Linux version of Skype. A lot of my premium features are missing, and I desperately need them for my job. I installed wine and winetricks, then I installed skype through wine and got this:

`Runtime error 217 at 00529055`

```
PlayOnLinux gives the same error on startup. I ran it in debug mode and got this:
```

`[01/30/15 11:30:55] - Running wine- Skype.exe (Working directory : /home/roman/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/SkypeTest/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone)
    fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
    fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
    fixme:ole:CoInitializeSecurity (0x44de10,-1,(nil),(nil),6,2,(nil),12352,(nil)) - stub!
    fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
    fixme:advapi:RegisterEventSourceW ((null),L"SkypeUpdate"): stub
    fixme:advapi:ReportEventW (0xcafe4242,0x0004,0x0001,0x00000064,(nil),0x0000,0x00000000,(nil),(nil)): stub
    fixme:advapi:DeregisterEventSource (0xcafe4242) stub
    fixme:ole:CoResumeClassObjects stub
    fixme:advapi:LsaOpenPolicy ((null),0x325904,0x00000001,0x3258fc) stub
    fixme:advapi:LsaClose (0xcafe) stub
    err:ole:TLB_ReadTypeLib Loading of typelib L"uc.tlb" failed with error 1006`

Comment: What are this skype premium features? Never heard of it. Also, have you check the wine app databates?

Comment: @xangua group screensharing/videocalls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Skype on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-use-skype-on-ubuntu)