# Getting an up-to-date Version of Skype?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, wine, skype

The officially distributed version of Skype for Ubuntu is really annoying to use (really outdated), and I want something as close as possible to the Windows experience. I have tried using WINE, which works not at all, and the Pidgin plugin is really rudimentary. I know there is always Hangouts, but all my friends are on Skype and that's not going to change. What method of Skype for Ubuntu gives the most updated experience and best sound quality?

(LUbuntu 14.04)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Skype on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-use-skype-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get the latest version of skype is from the [official website](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/). Unfortunently it's really outdated compared to the windows OS, but there's not much else to do but wait and hope until Microsoft releases a new update.

According to [WineHQ](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20164) someone managed to install Skype 5 using wine. Apparently setting the windows version to windows 8 allows it to work.