# Skype with wine crashes

Tags: wine, skype

I tried to install the latest Skype with the latest wine (1.7.38). While the installation itself worked, every time I start Skype, after a minute or so, it crashes.

[image]

Also, there is nothing that seems to be specifically causing the problem (that is, not a single action, or something similar, as there is no "common theme" for the crashes).

All of my wine settings are the default one except the Windows version setting (Windows 8). Yes, I know that it's entirely possible to run a native Skype, but that's old and horrible, so I'd prefer not to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-)  Actually, it's not old and horrible, but (still) secure with few bugs...  But let's hope that someone else is running the way you are (I'm using the native Skype) and that has it working...

Comment: You do know that there is a native client for skype ?

Comment: @Fabby thanks :) well, it isn't entirely horrible, but it's... not particularly good, either. And it isn't even near the most recent version.

Comment: Why don't you install Skype without Wine !! ... Use Wine only if an application is not available for Ubuntu.

Comment: How can you state it's an old version? The version number of Skype for Linux has nothing to do with the version number of Skype for Windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Skype on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-use-skype-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Wine Apps DB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31461) the only things that work with the latest Skype under wine are chat and file transfer.  Audio and video conferencing do not work.

Comment: Good one!  (Upvoted so it gets closer to the top!)