# "skype can't connect" error using wine

Tags: wine, internet, skype

I've been trying to get group video chat working on skype on ubuntu 15.10. The problem is, it is not supported in skype 4.3 (current linux release).

I have been trying to run newer versions of skype with wine. With v6.0 and up, I got runtime error 217, and I was unable to fix this.

I then tried using skype 5.0, which did launch using wine, but gave me the "unable to connect" message when I was sure I used the correct login credentials. Looks to me like skype can't access the Internet.

I was wondering if there was a fix for this problem that might allow internet access to skype 5.0 in wine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Skype on Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-use-skype-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

According to Wine, Login in on Skype for Wine does not work. You must edit your `Skype.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Skype 7 Wine
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/.../.wine" wine C:\\\\Program\\ Files\\ \\(x86\\)\\\\Skype\\\\Phone\\\\Skype.exe /username:"username" /password:"password"
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=Launch Skype 7 Wine
Path=/home/.../.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/
Icon=4F0B_SkypeIcon.0
```

[www.Winehq.org](http://winehq.org) [Skype for Linux](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-linux/)