# Installing skype from playonlinux

Tags: 16.04, skype

I'm trying to install skype using [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-run-windows-skype-on-ubuntu-using-wine) but after it installs it just opens up a blank skype application and the playonlinux wizard keeps loading (Says please wait) forever. Anyone have any idea what could be the problem ? :)

Comment: Close and exit skype completely, then the playonlinux installer should resume. It will ask you to create shortcuts, and then you can launch skype from playonlinux or the shortcuts you created.

Answer (score 5):

I hope I'm not misreading your intent.  If it is to have skype installed on your system, you should install the Ubuntu native skype support rather than trying to install the Windows version via playonlinux.  The playonlinux tool is for Windows applications which are don't have a native Linux version.

To install the linux version provided in the Canonical partner repository you can do this from a terminal commandline with the following three commands:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
$ sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

More details (including GUI process for those commands) can be found at:
[Skype - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype)

---

Update:

**New Native Linux Skype from Microsoft:**

There's a new Alpha release of Skype native for Linux:
[Skype for Linux Alpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) was released this year and have support for newer skype features that are not available in the repository version.  This includes being able to leave a voice message to an offline user.

Once the deb package is installed updates are available via regular system update checks.