# I Want Download Skype 16.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation, skype

I want install skype. I'm opening terminal and writing `sudo apt-get install skype` but terminal says:

```
E: Malformed entry 53 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed entry 53 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Why? Help please.

Comment: It means that the 53 line in your `sources.list` syntax is wrong, you should check  it, or show your `sources.list`.

Comment: first you should remove malformed and then try this http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/install-skype-4-3-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Thank you guys i solved my problem. Visit this site : ubuntuhandbook.org.Thank you for Mohamed for this site.

Answer (score -1):

See my answer for this..
[How to run Windows Skype on Ubuntu using Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/359023/how-to-run-windows-skype-on-ubuntu-using-wine/359024#359024)
 Scroll down to Native Skype on Ubuntu. I just edited it without seeing this question...  In short. 
There is a native Skype client for Ubuntu. You can open the Software and Updates applet included All Ubuntu flavors and click on the tab that says "Other Software". Make sure the Canonical Partners is ticked. Then you will be able to install the program through your favorite standard Ubuntu install method (software center, synaptic, or terminal).

or simply type:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```