# Running Skype on PlayOnLinux

Tags: wine, skype, playonlinux

Ok, so many may be wondering why I want to do this and not use any of the alternatives or the web based chat. One of the reasons is that few want to change. The other is because of MS's notorious database I want to make sure I have my own local chat history. And why on Linux? Because I don't trust Windows to run 24/7 (I'm anyways turning my 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 into a server, so).

So what's wrong with Skype 4.3 for Linux? Well, just recently whenever I launch Skype and when it is trying to sync the chat logs it crashes.

I tried to follow the following tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/a/722140/195219

The only problem is that I cannot access the link to that particular version of Skype needed. I wanted to ask about it as a comment but I have far too few reputation points for that. I thought I'd break a rule and ask about it as an answer but it was deleted and recommended that I ask a new question.

So after all that the question becomes, does anyone have a copy of this particular version of Skype so I can get it running on PlayOnLinux? Or ask Galgalesh to fix the link?

Answer (score 1):

Do not try run Skype on PlayOnLinux and install [Skype for Linux Alpha](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299). I think it's more comfortable and easier.

Comment: You mean the 4.3 version? I told you it refuses to launch anymore.

Comment: No.. New Alpha version. It is i think 1.1.x..

Comment: You didn't hear about this new project?

Comment: Actually, a problem... That deb seems to be made for 64-bit machines only. This old 14.04 machine is 32-bit. At least that's what I get from Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: Did you try look for source? If you find source, you can configure and make it for your distribution.

Comment: Doesn't look like anyone has given out any source for me to build... Apart from Ghetto Skype.

Answer (score -1):

here you can find the respective **winehq.org**-entries on skype:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1592

And here is an older skype.community entry on older versions:

https://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Getting-older-version-of-skype/td-p/99846

Comment: None of those older version links seemed to work (or wasn't quite the right version).

Comment: well perhaps try it wit the highest 6.something-version from http://filehippo.com/download_skype/history/5/ -

Comment: The specified blob does not exist.

Comment: okay sorry my fault